# react bind to checkbox and update state base on checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Try to check the checkbox, you will see undefined. That's strange I think I used `find` properly. Or there's a better way to do it?

http://jsbin.com/ficijuwexa/1/edit?js,console,output

```
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      "fruits":[
        {"name":"banana","value":true},
        {"name":"watermelon","value":false},
        {"name":"lemon","value":true},
      ]
    }
  }

  handleChange(e,key){        
    const newFruitsData = this.state.fruits.find(obj => {
        obj.name === key ? obj.value = e.target.checked : ''
    });
    console.log(newFruitsData) // <-- why does this output undefined?
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.fruits.map(obj => 
           <div key={obj.name}>
           <label>{obj.name}</label>
           <input onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, obj.name)} type="checkbox" defaultChecked={obj.value} />
            </div>
         )}
         <br />
         <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.fruits,null,2)}</pre>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your find has no return statement, it always return undefined while it should return boolean

```
const newFruitsData = this.state.fruits.find(obj => obj.name === key && obj.value === e.target.checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the handleChange(), the Array.prototype.find should return Bool:

```
handleChange(e,key){
    let nxState = Object.assign({}, this.state)
    nxState.fruits.find(obj => {
      if (obj.name === key) {
        obj.value = e.target.checked
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    });
    this.setState(nxState)
}
```

And you should use `setState()` instead, it's my opinion of course

--- Update

[Check it](http://jsbin.com/qamabamitu/1/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: Like how? like this wouldn't work http://jsbin.com/bisadepeso/1/edit?html,js,console,output